# Can adding too much yeast to my sugar wash mess up fermentation?

Tags: first-time-brewer, first-time, vodka

I am starting my own vodka with a 4 gallon sugar wash. I added 10 lb of sugar and a whole pack of turbo yeast (for a 5.5 gallon wash). I read a little bit that adding too much might make the temperature rise and kill the remaining yeast. My wash has been sitting for a little over a day and has stayed steady at 90.5 degrees Fahrenheit. Will this mess up fermentation or affect the flavor of my vodka after distillation?

Answer (score 0):

Too much yeast may impart a "yeasty" flavour on the finished ferment, but that's about it. It is rarely a driving factor in run-away fermentation temperatures.

Temperature spikes during a high-stress fermentation are a very real risk, but this is generally not a factor of pitching rates. When yeast ferments sugar it essentially digests it and, just like the digestion of food keeps the human body warm, this will also produce heat in yeast cells. If the temperature of the fermentation rises this will increase the rate of fermentation which in turn will increase the rate of heat production, and so on. This vicious circle is known as a "runaway" fermentation and as a result fermentations have been known to go volcanic, climb out of the fermenter and make a big mess.

Temperature spikes are are a factor of attenuation rates early in the fermentation, which means that starting gravity is the main driving factor. The higher the gravity, the more vigorous the initial fermentation will be and the more heat will be produced. More yeast will contribute somewhat to this scenario, but compared to the effect that starting gravity and pitching temperature have this is a minor issue only.

The main risk about too high a fermentation temperature is that it will produce higher alcohols which in turn will result in a harsh, hot and solvent-like product that can give you monumental hangovers. However, it is extremely rare for such a fermentation to reach temperatures that will kill the yeast. The latter is possible in industrial fermentations that use specialized yeasts which can ferment out a high gravity wash in under 24 hours,which are typically done in temperature-controlled fermenters with glycol cooling. In a homebrew scenario this rarely happens.

Rule of thumb for high gravity (sugar wash) fermentations with starting gravities of 1.100 or more:

- Pitch enough yeast (it's far easier and more serious to under-pitch than to over-pitch);
- Aerate well
- Provide enough yeast nutrients
- For sugar washes provide a pH buffer to keep the acidity in check (yeast produces organic acids and if the acidity becomes too much the yeast will go inactive before the fermentation is complete)
- For really high gravity washes add your sugar in stages (this is known as a stepped fermentation); e.g. divide your sugar in two or three batches and add each subsequent batch once the gravity of the wash has dropped to about 50% of the starting gravity.
- Pitch cool and let the temperature rise slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

An over pitch of turbo will do nothing but excellerate fermentation. over putch is only an issue of you're looking for yeast esters in the flavor profile. Turbo has little to none unless under pitched.

As far as heat death, I've never seen a strain that can generate more heat than they can live through.